# Why do I need to call attr_writer methods with `self` to get them to work inside a class?

Tags: ruby

This does not output anything:

```
class Test

  attr_accessor :value

  def run
    set_value
    puts value
  end

  def set_value
    value = 6 # No 'self'
  end
end

Test.new.run
```

Whereas this outputs '6'

```
class Test

  attr_accessor :value

  def run
    set_value
    puts value
  end

  def set_value
    self.value = 6 # With 'self'
  end
end

Test.new.run
```

Why do I need `self` when the method is defined already? Surely Ruby should use the method rather than creating a local variable in the set_value function?

Answer (score 7):

*Why do I need `self` when the method is defined already?*

[Assignment Methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment+Methods)

> When using method assignment you must always have a receiver. If you do not have a receiver Ruby assumes you are assigning to a local variable

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an instance variable with the '@' character :

```
value = 6 # create a local variable 'value' and set it to 6

@value = 6 # create an instance variable named 'value' and set it to 6, it will be accessible through the accessor #value
```

#### EDIT

```
self.value = 6
```

calls the method #value=(new_value), implicitly declared from attr_accessor, which sets the @value instance variable to new_value (possible from other scopes)

```
@value = 6
```

directly sets the instance variable to 6 (only possible from instance scope)

Answer (score 0):

You always need to use self so ruby can know if you're not instantiating a new variable:

```
self.value = 6 #ruby knows it's your class variable

value = 6 #ruby thinks you're creating a new variable called value
```

[Assignment Methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment+Methods)